# Loop through rows of dataframe using re.compile().split()

Tags: python, regex, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a dataframe taht consists of 1 column and several rows. Each of these rows is constructed in the same way: -timestamp- value1 value2 value3 -timestamp- value 4 value5 value6 ...

The timestamps have this format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` and the values are number with 2 decimals.
I would like to make a new dataframe that has the individual timestamps in one row and the related values in the next row.

I managed to get the expected result linewise with regex but not for the entire dataframe.

My code so far:

```
#input dataframe
data.head()

                  values
0   2020-05-12 10:00:00 12.07 13 11.56 ... 2020-05-12 10:00:01 11.49 17 5.67...
1   2020-05-12 10:01:00 11.49 17 5.67 ... 2020-05-12 10:01:01 12.07 13 11.56...
2   2020-05-12 10:02:00 14.29 18 11.28 ... 2020-05-12 10:02:01 13.77 18 7.43...


test = data['values'].iloc[0] #first row of data
row1 = re.compile("(\d\d\d\d\S\d\d\S\d\d\s\d\d\S\d\d\S\d\d)").split(test)
df_row1 = pd.DataFrame(row1)

df_row1.head()

             values 
0   2020-05-12 10:00:00
1   12.07 13.79 15.45 17.17 18.91 14.91 12.35 14....
2   2020-05-12 10:00:01
3   12.48 13.96 13.88 15.57 18.46 15.0 13.65 14.6...

#trying the same for the entire dataframe 
for row in data:
    df_new = re.compile("(\d\d\d\d\S\d\d\S\d\d\s\d\d\S\d\d\S\d\d)").split(row)

print(df_new)
['values']
```

My question now is how can I loop through the rows of my dataframe and get the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to first split the lines and extract the values to columns, be aware you can use `str.extract`. Using named grouping in your regular expression it will automatically assign the columns for your dataframe

```py
split_line = r"\s+(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})"
extract_values = r"(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s(?P<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s(?P<value_one>.*?)\s(?P<value_two>.*?)\s(?P<value_three>.*?)$"

df = pd.DataFrame([{
    "value": "2020-05-12 10:00:00 12.07 13 11.56 2020-06-12 11:00:00 13.07 16 11.16 2020-05-12 10:00:01 11.49 17 5.67", 
},{
    "value": "2020-05-13 10:00:00 14.07 13 15.56 2020-05-16 10:00:02 11.51 18 5.69", 
}])
df = df["value"].str.split(split_line).explode().str.extract(extract_values, expand=True)
print(df)
#          date      time value_one value_two value_three
# 0  2020-05-12  10:00:00     12.07        13       11.56
# 0  2020-06-12  11:00:00     13.07        16       11.16
# 0  2020-05-12  10:00:01     11.49        17        5.67
# 1  2020-05-13  10:00:00     14.07        13       15.56
# 1  2020-05-16  10:00:02     11.51        18        5.69
```

In case you do not know the number of groups after the date and time use `split` rather than a regular expression. I would suggest something like this:

```py
split_line = r"\s+(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})"

df = pd.DataFrame([{
    "value": "2020-05-12 10:00:00 12.07 13 11.56 2020-06-12 11:00:00 13.07 16 11.16 2020-05-12 10:00:01 11.49 17 5.67", 
},{
    "value": "2020-05-13 10:00:00 14.07 13 14 15 15.56 2020-05-16 10:00:02 11.51 18 5.69", 
}])
df = df["value"].str.split(split_line).explode().reset_index()

df = df['value'].str.split(" ").apply(pd.Series)
df.columns = [f"col_{col}" for col in df.columns]
print(df)
#         col_0     col_1  col_2 col_3  col_4 col_5  col_6
# 0  2020-05-12  10:00:00  12.07    13  11.56   NaN    NaN
# 1  2020-06-12  11:00:00  13.07    16  11.16   NaN    NaN
# 2  2020-05-12  10:00:01  11.49    17   5.67   NaN    NaN
# 3  2020-05-13  10:00:00  14.07    13     14    15  15.56
# 4  2020-05-16  10:00:02  11.51    18   5.69   NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot! Your idea with the automatically assigned columns is very nice, but in my real dataframe I have over 2000 values that would need >2000 columns and writing `(?P<value_X>.*?)` 2000 times is not very efficient. Can you think of a shorter version? It would be okay if the column names are a number array, e.g. 0-2000?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop through the rows to get the result instead, you can use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split the given series around the delimiter, the delimiter in this case would be a regular expression. Then you can use [`DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to transform each element in a list-likes to seperate rows.

Use:

```
data["values"] = data["values"].str.split(r'\s+(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})')
data = data.explode("values")
data["values"] = data["values"].str.split(r'(?<=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+')
data = data.explode("values").reset_index(drop=True)

print(data)
```

This resulting dataframe `data` should look like:

```
        values
0   2020-05-12 10:00:00
1        12.07 13 11.56
2   2020-05-12 10:00:01
3         11.49 17 5.67
4   2020-05-12 10:01:00
5         11.49 17 5.67
6   2020-05-12 10:01:01
7        12.07 13 11.56
8   2020-05-12 10:02:00
9        14.29 18 11.28
10  2020-05-12 10:02:01
11        13.77 18 7.43
```